# How to Open only UserForm of an excel macro from batch file

Tags: vba, excel, batch-file

I'm trying to open the UserForm1 of an excel macro through batch file. I'm able to open that but excel is also getting opened along with that. I want only UserForm1 to be opened not the excel. Below is my approach :

I have written a macros to open the UserForm1

```
Sub open_form()
   UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

In batch File:

```
@echo off
cd "c:\Test\"
openFormTest.xlsm
```

By the above approach, When I'm running the batch file both UserForm1 and excel are getting open, but I want to open only UserForm1. Kindly help me out

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to show the `UserForm` in `modeless` mode and then hide the application.

try this

```
Sub open_form()
    Application.Visible = False
    UserForm1.Show vbModeless
End Sub
```

and either in a button you need to set it back to true or you can use the `UserForm_QueryClose` event

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    Application.Visible = True
    ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Application.Visible=false will hide all open excel workbook, any suggestion?

Answer (score 5):

There are several reasons (such as unhandled exceptions crashing your code before `Application.Visible` is reset to `True`) that it is not a good idea to do this but I'll assume you have considered these:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize() 
    Application.Visible = False 
End Sub 

Private Sub UserForm_Terminate() 
    Application.Visible = True 
End Sub 

Private Sub Workbook_Open() 
    UserForm1.Show vbModeless
End Sub
```

Comment: One suggestion though :) You need to show the form in modeless mode else the form will also hide.

Comment: @leemo As you have said it's not a good idea, may I know in what respect you are saying this

Comment: @Samraan I editted my answer with one example of why its not a good idea. If the code crashes and Application.Visible is still false. The user's current and future Excel instance will remain hidden until someone goes into the VB console and resets it to True.

Answer (score 5):

In case someone wants to run a userform "alike" a stand alone application:

Issues I was facing:

1. I did not want to use the Workbook_Open Event as the excel is locked in read only.
2. The batch command is limited that the fact that (to my knowledge) it cannot call the macro.

I first wrote a macro to launch my userform while hiding the application (based on your comments above):

```
Sub open_form()
 Application.Visible = False
 frmAddClient.Show vbModeless
End Sub
```

I then created a vbs to launch this macro (doing it with a relative path has been tricky):

```
dim fso
dim curDir
dim WinScriptHost
set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
curDir = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".")
set fso = nothing

Set xlObj = CreateObject("Excel.application")
xlObj.Workbooks.Open curDir & "\Excels\CLIENTES.xlsb"
xlObj.Run "open_form"
```

And I finally did a batch file to execute the VBS...

```
@echo off
pushd %~dp0
cscript Add_Client.vbs
```

Note that I have also included the "Set back to visible" in my `Userform_QueryClose`:

```
Private Sub cmdClose_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
    Application.Visible = True
    Application.Quit
End Sub
```