# How to Close excel macros through batch file without any save changes?

Tags: excel, batch-file

I want to close the excel file through batch file. I have opened UserForm1 and I need to run the batch file to closed this UserForm along with excel without any save changes

Comment: I have already answered your question [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20603599/how-to-open-only-userform-of-an-excel-macro-from-batch-file)

Comment: I'm asking through batch file not with macros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike vbscript, you cannot create objects and interact with them. To close an Excel workbook from a batch file you will have to kill the Excel application.

```
taskkill /f /im Excel.exe
```

However, I am not in favor of closing Excel in this manner.

Comment: Ok! You are right even I felt now this is not the efficient way after applying this