# Most User Friendly Way to use a VBA EXCEL Userform?

Tags: excel, vba, user-interface, userform

So I have programmed several userform with several user inputs(text boxes, check boxes, etc.) Now how can I use them outside of excel?

Currently I have to:

```
Open up the spreadsheet
Enable macros
Go to Developer Tab, View Code
Then find the right userform and run it or type F5.
```

Is there a more user-friendly way to run the userform? Its for testers who don't know vba or excel programming.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, absolutely. You could create a button named after the form in question, and to that button assign the following macro:

```
Sub btn1()
    frm1.Show
End sub
```

That's it! Of course, change the names according to what you have :)
I also reccomend having a button to close the form on the form itself.

OF COURSE this still uses Excel. If you want to use them on their own you could have something like this guy did: [How to Open only UserForm of an excel macro from batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20603599/how-to-open-only-userform-of-an-excel-macro-from-batch-file)

Comment: is it possible to run the macro without using excel atnall? Maybe on a website or a standalone executable?

Comment: I'm not sure since you coded it in VBA, but you could code it in VB.net and save it as an executable. It's the same language, you have to use it through MS visual studio though. I found this video but I can't watch it at work. Hoping it's good for you ;) www.youtube.com/watch?v=3nlJuW0yK6U