# Excel to only show userform, never show workbook

Tags: excel, vba, userform, commandbutton

I have currently got a workbook which is hidden when it is opened and my userform shows. I have a button which sends emails after storing it on the workbook. When i press send it unhides the workbook. how can i stop this from happening. I also have a combobox which shows a list of items. I am still struggling on how to dynamically show labels and text boxes based on the selection.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.Visible = False
voneServiceRequest.Show
End Sub


Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
'Copy Data Into Worksheet'
Worksheets("Order").Range("A1").Value = TextBox1.Value
Worksheets("Order").Range("A3").Value = TextBox2.Value
Worksheets("Order").Range("B4").Value = TextBox3.Value
Worksheets("Order").Range("B5").Value = SiteList.Text
Worksheets("Order").Range("B6").Value = TextBox4.Value
Worksheets("Order").Range("B7").Value = TextBox5.Value
Worksheets("Order").Range("B8").Value = TextBox6.Value
Worksheets("Order").Range("A10").Value = TextBox7.Value
Worksheets("Order").Range("B11").Value = RequestList.Text
Worksheets("Order").Range("A13").Value = TextBox8.Value
End Sub

Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Dim FileExtStr As String
    Dim FileFormatNum As Long
    Dim Sourcewb As Workbook
    Dim Destwb As Workbook
    Dim TempFilePath As String
    Dim TempFileName As String
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    Set Sourcewb = ActiveWorkbook

    'Copy the ActiveSheet to a new workbook
    ActiveSheet.Copy
    Set Destwb = ActiveWorkbook

    'Determine the Excel version and file extension/format
    With Destwb
        If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
            'You use Excel 97-2003
            FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
        Else
            'You use Excel 2007-2013
            Select Case Sourcewb.FileFormat
            Case 51: FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
            Case 52:
                If .HasVBProject Then
                    FileExtStr = ".xlsm": FileFormatNum = 52
                Else
                    FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
                End If
            Case 56: FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
            Case Else: FileExtStr = ".xlsb": FileFormatNum = 50
            End Select
        End If
    End With

    'Save the new workbook/Mail it/Delete it
    TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
    TempFileName = ActiveSheet.Name & " " & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy")

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With Destwb
        .SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .to = "muhammad.qahar@vodafone.com"
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "RFS ORDER FORM [Insert Ref Here]"
            .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
            .Body = "Hi, Please find attached the order form"




            .Attachments.Add Destwb.FullName

            .Display   ' .Send or use .Display
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
        .Close savechanges:=False
    End With

    'Delete the file you have send
    Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

End Sub



Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
Worksheets("Order").Range("B4:B8").ClearContents
Worksheets("Order").Range("B11").ClearContents
End Sub

Sub UserForm_Initialize()

'Lock Labels on Worksheet'


'Add site list upon opening form'

With SiteList
    .AddItem "Birmingham"
    .AddItem "Bristol"
    .AddItem "Cardiff"
    .AddItem "Chelmsford"
    .AddItem "Edinburgh"
    .AddItem "Fenchurch Street"
    .AddItem "Glasgow"
    .AddItem "Guernsey"
    .AddItem "Halifax"
    .AddItem "Homeworker"
    .AddItem "Horsham"
    .AddItem "Ipswich"
    .AddItem "Jersey"
    .AddItem "Leeds"
    .AddItem "Leicester"
    .AddItem "Lennox Wood"
    .AddItem "Liverpool"
    .AddItem "Manchester"
    .AddItem "Peterborough"
    .AddItem "Redhill"
    .AddItem "Sunderland"
    .AddItem "Madrid"
End With

'Add list of requests upon opening form'

With RequestList
    .AddItem "Add Phone To VONE C", 0
    .AddItem "Add FMC", 1
    .AddItem "Add Voicemail", 2
    .AddItem "Create New Pickup Group", 3
    .AddItem "Create New Hunt Group", 4
    .AddItem "Dialling Permissions (Class of Service)", 5
    .AddItem "MMR", 6
    .AddItem "Name Change", 7
    .AddItem "New User", 8
    .AddItem "Pick Up Group Changes i.e Add/Remove User", 9
    .AddItem "Hunt Group Changes i.e. Add/Remove User", 10
    .AddItem "Remove Phone From VONE C", 11
    .AddItem "Remove User From VONE C", 12
    .AddItem "Remove FMC Capability", 13
    .AddItem "Remove Voicemail Capability", 14
End With

'Hide information required'

RequestList.Style = fmStyleDropDownList
frAddPhone.Visible = False

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Windows("RFS User Form Mock.xlsm").Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub LegendDefinition_Change()
'Locks box from being edited by users'

LegendDefinition.Locked = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You want to say that worksheet is hidden, not a workbook, am I right? And what you mean saying "When i press send", "Send" on outlook menu or some of your buttons?

Comment: Which button sends the email, command button 1,2 or 4? Also what happens if you place `Application.Visible = False` after the email is sent?

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. so I have a send button on the userform. When i press that it drafts the email up no problem. however it also makes the entire application visible again. In regards to worksheet, i would like the entire workbook to be hidden as this will be used for my customers but i dont them to have visibility of that. CommandButton3 is the email send

Comment: Well this could help https://stackoverflow.com/a/20603619/1365754

Comment: What about the second part guys any idea? I have an exact copy of the form on a spreadsheet and ive used a index formula to show list of items based on selection of combobox selection. However i dont know how to translate that to a userform :/